# Prana in hands while meditating?

Tags: yoga, meditation, pranayama

While trying a certain breathing technique while meditating a few weeks ago, I began feeling a peculiar sensation in my hands. It felt like an internal buzzing or as if my hands were filled with light. Upon moving my palms and fingers closer together, I could feel very distinct "energy fields", for lack of a better term. As I moved them about, it was as if I was feeling and manipulating the shape of this field. The best I could compare it to is a magnetic field, or as if there were millions of tiny magnets in each hand.

I used to be an atheist, but after meditating for the past year and having this very eye-opening experience, I don't know anymore. Also, forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask such question, but perhaps this energy I feel is a type of prana.

What am I experiencing and how do I enhance this new sense?

Edit: I should note this has happened on multiple occasions and often sticks around for up to an hour after meditating.

Comment: That's prana, to be more precise your subtle body, which is Narayana. Also all Hindu God's, deities are real by the way.

Comment: To enhance this sense you should try to be more and more aware of the experience... the more aware you become the more  you increase it... and you can also try some other meditation methods too.. like various methods described in Vijnana Bhairava Tantra...

Comment: keep doing your meditation practice

Comment: I find the metaphor of magnets a little baffling...

Comment: ...in this context

Comment: @MoziburUllah It's been over a year and I'm still baffled.

Comment: @graviton: I don't understand what you mean. I'm baffled by the remark since we are not geberally affected by magnetic fields so to describe some aspect of ourselves in terms of that seems odd, to say the least ...

Comment: You are experiencing being focused: if you keep your hands in a certain position your hand muscles tend to fixate. So no it is not prana: it is just your body working. It is just you being relaxed. Keep on meditating and lead a relaxing life style it is good for your health. Do not subscribe to mystical things and remain critical.